# How to select nodes between tags

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm writing a code to extract node after `h3` tags in Selenium through XPath. Here is a [page](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/2476171-create-and-edit-formulas-in-smartsheet#toc-edit-an-existing-formula) that I'm using.

From this page, I need all the data following `h3`. I've got a for-loop to get all the `h3`s on my page. I need to know how I can get the data following the current `h3`.

Here is (a piece of) my code:

```
List<WebElement> contents = driver.findElements(By.xpath("descendant::*[@class='node__content']/descendant::h3"));
for (int j = 1; j <= contents.size(); j++) {
    String title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("descendant::*[@class='node__content']/descendant::h3[" + j + "]")).getText();
    String answer=// I want to get the data following the selected h3
}
```

I tried xpath as `descendant::*[@class='node__content']/descendant::h3[1]/following::*` but this is selecting all the content. I want the content that is between current h3 and the next h3. If it is the last h3, select rest of the content in the div.

How can I do this?

[image]

Here I've multiple `h3`s(3) as per the screenshot attached.

From my `for-loop`, I want to assign the following:

```
title: Avoid printing all columns (Grid View)
answer: node(s) between `h3[1]` and `h3[2]`

title: Include blank rows in your printout
answer: node(s) between `h3[2]` and `h3[3]`

title: Gantt Chart included in the printout
answer: following::node(s) from `h3[3]` till the end.
```

In other words. if I do `driver.findElement(By.xpath("descendant::*[@class='node__content']/descendant::h3[" + j + "]/following-sibling[1]"))`, I can get all the first `p` tag data, but I don't want to limit just to 1 `following-sibling`. I want to extract everything till the next `h3`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape? Maybe we can route you through a better path. Saying I want to extract `h3` following tag is ambiguous. I would like to know what exactly you are trying to extract from the webpage?

Comment: Hi @cruisepandeym thanks for the quick edit. I've updated my question, Can you please let me know If my case is clear.